# Null pointer dereference with __gxx_personality_v0

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have an ndk-build project in Android and I want to do analysis with the Android Studio Profiler in 3.2. But I always get a crash:

```
2019-02-20 10:10:42.369 21888-21888/? A/DEBUG: pid: 21705, tid: 21882, name: engine  >>> com.test.example <<<
2019-02-20 10:10:42.369 21888-21888/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x1f
2019-02-20 10:10:42.369 21888-21888/? A/DEBUG: Cause: null pointer dereference
2019-02-20 10:10:42.369 21888-21888/? A/DEBUG:     r0 bc281b60  r1 ffffffff  r2 bb704199  r3 bb4e9400
2019-02-20 10:10:42.369 21888-21888/? A/DEBUG:     r4 bc281b08  r5 bc281b60  r6 f0230240  r7 bc281aa8
2019-02-20 10:10:42.369 21888-21888/? A/DEBUG:     r8 bb704100  r9 d149a598  sl 00000001  fp 00000000
2019-02-20 10:10:42.369 21888-21888/? A/DEBUG:     ip bb76c6f4  sp bc281aa8  lr bb6d4083  pc bb6d447e  cpsr 80000030
2019-02-20 10:10:42.372 21888-21888/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2019-02-20 10:10:42.372 21888-21888/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 002b047e  /data/app/com.test.example-JNm5Mn25Zd3obHmkwErCEg==/lib/arm/mylib.so
2019-02-20 10:10:42.372 21888-21888/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 002b007f  /data/app/com.test.example-JNm5Mn25Zd3obHmkwErCEg==/lib/arm/mylib.so
2019-02-20 10:10:42.372 21888-21888/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 002adee5  /data/app/com.test.example-JNm5Mn25Zd3obHmkwErCEg==/lib/arm/mylib.so
2019-02-20 10:10:42.372 21888-21888/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 002ade93  /data/app/com.test.example-JNm5Mn25Zd3obHmkwErCEg==/lib/arm/mylib.so (__gxx_personality_v0+270)
2019-02-20 10:10:42.372 21888-21888/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0018175c  /data/data/com.test.example/libperfa_arm.so
2019-02-20 10:10:42.372 21888-21888/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00182080  /data/data/com.test.example/libperfa_arm.so
```

As far as I know, `__gxx_personality_v0` is related to the exception mechanism in C++. But how do I fix this issue?

The only thing I have tried is if I add `-fno-exceptions` flag in my library then this issue is solved. But I am wondering if there has some other solution here, as `no-exception` is not consistent with the STL library.

Comment: Post your code please, e.g. the related Java classes and the JNI functions.

Comment: @shizhen The codebase in my lib is too large, I am not sure which part I should post here.

Comment: What version of the NDK are you using? What STL? What compiler? What build system? If not the latest NDK, libc++, and Clang, try updating.